# Is there a way to prevent Vagrant from auto-sharing /vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm using FreeBSD 10 with Vagrant and run into a problem with shared folders, which are currently not supported on FreeBSD 10 VirtualBox guest additions. I get around the problem by using the rsync method for sharing folders. However, Vagrant ALWAYS tries to load the working folder at /vagrant.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `config.vm.synced_folder` method, by setting the disabled option - with this you can disable previously configured synced folders, including the default (at least, it worked for me with the default too):

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

See: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html